# Prove that $\operatorname{rank}(L_{A})=\operatorname{rank}(L_{A^\top})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove $\operatorname{rank}(L_{A})=\operatorname{rank}(L_{A^\top})$ and $A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb F)$ by using two facts. 1. If $W$ is a subspace of $V$ which is a finite dimensional vector space, then $\dim(W)+\dim(W^{\circ})=\dim(V)$. 2. Suppose that $W$ and $V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces and that $T:V \to W$ is linear. Then $N(T^{\top})=R(T)^{\circ}$. Notation : $S^{\circ}=\{f\in V^{\ast}|f(S)=0\}$means the annihilator of $S$ and $T^{\top}:W^{\ast}\to V^{\ast}$ is defined by $T^{\top}(g)=gT$ for all $g\in W^{\ast}$.
My attempt of the proof:
$$\operatorname{rank}(L_A)=\dim(R(L_A))=m-\dim(R(L_A)^{\circ}) $$ by fact 1. $$=m-(N(L_A^{\top}))$$by fact 2. $$=\dim(R(L_A^{\top}))$$ by dimension theorem. I have no idea to keep going. Thanks for someone helping me.

Comment: what does $L_A$ means?

Comment: @AmanPandey $L_A(x)=Ax$ where $x\in \Bbb F^{n}$

Comment: You can prove $\ker A=M^\tau$ where $M$ is the column-space of $A^\tau$, i.e., the row-space of $A$. You can check this easily by solving the system $A\cdot X=0$. It follows directly from the matrix multiplication definition., so $\ker A=M^\tau=\Omega$. and $\dim\Omega=n-\operatorname{rank} A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me call $\textsf T$ your $L_A : \mathbb F^n \to \mathbb F^m$. Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb F^n$; $e_1^*,\dots,e_n^*$ the corresponding dual basis, and consider the unique linear map $\phi : (\mathbb F^n)^* \to \mathbb F^n$ such that $\phi(e_i^*) = e_i$. Now, since $\phi$ is an isomorphism (why?) the dimensions of $R(\textsf T^t)$ and $\phi \big( R(\textsf T^t) \big)$ coincide. Finally, check that $\phi \big( R(\textsf T^t) \big)$ is precisely the image of the linear map $x \mapsto A^tx$. As a hint, what is the matrix representation of $\textsf T^t$?

Comment: I have already known that $\phi$ is an isomorphism from $\Bbb (F^{n})^{*} $ onto $\Bbb F^{n}$ and since $R(T^{t})$ is a subspace of $(F^{n})^{*}$, $\dim\big( R(T^{t})\big)=\dim \Big( \phi\big( R(T^{t})\big)\Big)$.

Comment: But I have no idea to prove that $\Big( \phi\big( R(T^{t})\big)\Big)=R(L_{A^\top})$. I know that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are standard ordered basis for $\Bbb F^{n}$ and $\Bbb F^{m}$, respectively. Let $\alpha^{*}$ and $\beta^{*}$ be the dual basis. Then $[T]_{\beta^{*}}^{\alpha^{*}}=A^\top$. Should I prove it by given $x\in R(L_{A^\top})$,then $x=A^\top y$ for some $y\in \Bbb F^{m}$ and using the equality $[T]_{\beta^{*}}^{\alpha^{*}}=A^\top$ (But I don't know how.) Thanks a lot.

Comment: You going in the right way! Observe that, $y \in \mathbb F^m$ is some coordinate vector $[g]_{\beta^*}$, so, $x = A^ty = [\textsf T^t]_{\beta^*}^{\alpha^*}[g]_{\beta^*} = [\textsf T^t(g)]_{\alpha^*}$, that is, $x = \phi(\textsf T^t(g))$ which proves that $x \in \phi \big( R(\textsf T^t) \big)$.

Comment: Suppose $x\in R(L_{A^\top})$, we have $x=A^\top y$ for some $y \in \Bbb F^{m}$, by the discussion above, $A^\top y=[T^{\top}]_{\beta^{*}}^{\alpha^{*}}[g]_{\beta^{*}}$, since $y=(y_1, \dots,y_m)^{\top}=\sum_{i=1}^m y_ie_i=\sum_{i=1}^my_i\phi(e_i^{*})=\phi\big( \sum_{i=1}^my_ie_i^{*} \big)=\phi(g)$ for some $g\in  (\Bbb F^m)^*$, where $\phi: (\Bbb F^m)^*\to \Bbb F$ and $e_i^*\in \Bbb F^m$ is similar to the above definition.

Comment: For the converse, given $x\in \phi \big( R(T^{\top}) \big)$, then $x=\phi \big( T^{\top}(g) \big)$ for some $g\in (\Bbb F^m)^*$. So $x=\phi \big( T^{\top}(g) \big)=[T^{\top}(g)]_{\alpha^*}=[T^{\top}]_{\beta^{*}}^{\alpha^{*}}[g]_{\beta^*}=A^{\top}y$, for some $y\in \Bbb F^m $. $ \big([g]_{\beta^*}=\phi(g)\in \Bbb F^m , \phi:(\Bbb F^m)^*\to \Bbb F \big)$ So, $x\in R(L_{A^\top})$, which finishes this proof. Thanks a lot.